# Proper way of working with DocumentDB and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

I am connecting to AWS DocumentDB from a Lambda function. In order to be able to do this I had to attach lambda to the default VPC (that's where DocumentDB cluster is running) and the default (public) subnets. But, this has caused my Lambda to timeout whenever trying make an outbound request, e.g. push message to SQS. This, I want to avoid.

So what is the recommended way of connecting to DocumentDB without loosing functionality that occurs when putting Lambda in the VPC? There's gotta be a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda functions in a VPC never get a public IP address. So if the function needs to access both VPC resources and other resources outside of the VPC the function has to be deployed only to private subnets with routes to a NAT Gateway.

Alternatively, if the only external resources you need to access are other AWS services, then you could add [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html) for those services to the VPC.